# Create Jenkins job DSL with readYaml

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

i need to use readYaml function in job DSL.
i tried to use snakeYaml and it worked ok in my localhost environment, but failed in our business environment. The error as below:

```
ERROR: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.29.1: not found]
```

I think it is due to our business environment has network limit. I would like to use readYaml which is available in Pipeline Utility Steps plugin. Please help to advise !